# Can the Laplace transform of Dirac delta function be explained in sense of Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

[image]

This is what has been explained in my differential equation lecture.
But I have no idea how this explanation can be justified in the sense of Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral (Actually this course is for sophomore and general measure is never mentioned in this lecture.)

I think that the above mathematical equation has two problem in the sense of Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral.

1. Since $\delta_a(t-t_0)$ cannot be dominated by an integral function, we cannot apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence thm, and change the order of integral and limit.
2. Indeed the $\delta(t-t_0)e^{-st}=0$ except for $t=t_0$, the integral value must be zero.

I think that we need general measure (maybe Dirac measure) to rigorously explain $\mathcal L{\delta(t-t_0)}=e^{-st_0}$.

Am I right?

Comment: What is $\delta_a(t-t_0)$? I usually think of $\delta$ as a distribution, or  linear functional, on $C^\infty_c\left(\mathbb{R}\right) \to \mathbb{R}$. However, here, the domain is only the half-line $[0,\infty)$, not the entire line, so there may be some ambiguity in how to define such an integral. Also, I don't think the details of the integral matter too much when using $\delta$; in this case, the integral can be thought of as just a linear operator satisfying some nice properties.

Comment: Sorry for not clearly mention about the definition of δa(t−t0) . In this context, δa(t−t0)=(1/2a)*X_[t0-a,t0+a), where X_[t0-a,t0+a) denotes the characteristic function on [t0-a,t0+a). By the way what does "some nice properties" mean?

Comment: For example, integration by parts to define $\delta'$. If you are interesting in thinking about distribution theory, $\delta$ is *defined* as the linear functional satisfying $\delta(f):=\int \delta(x) f(x)\,dx=f(0)$. However, I suspect this is not what you're looking for. The only step in the calculation that might demand some more thought is the first equality.

Comment: I think that you exactly know what I'm curious about. Anyway your comment also gave me a great help in practical and intuitional sense. Thank you :)